# Why is "schematics" used in its plural form for a single item?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, terminology, uncountable-nouns

I am a visitor from [Electronics.SE](//electronics.stackexchange.com), where we often discuss the schematics for various devices. Mostly asking a user to post the schematics, because it is impossible to follow someone's thoughts without it.

Since English is not my native language, I have had a hard time understanding the difference between *schematic* and *schematics*. Initially I assumed that *schematic**s*** is the plural form of *schematic*, but it did not take long to realize that *schematic**s*** is being used even when there's only one page or circuit.

What are the rules governing the usage of this word? Does it belong to a specific type of words with a fancy name that I can search for?

Comment: This might be a semantic issue where *schematic* is a reference to the diagram itself and *schematics* is a step-by-step breakdown of said diagram.

Comment: This plural is a common use in fields where illustration and documentation ordinarily requires many related documents. The *schematics* typically include many *schematic diagrams*--perhaps a separate diagram for each layer or subsystem--just as the *blueprints* for a building typically include many floor plans and detailed drawings, and the *elevations* for a stage set typically include many illustrations and color renderings.

Comment: Could you link an example where "schematics" is used for a single item? A single item (meaning one "diagram" only) should be *schematic* (as a noun) or *schematic diagram* (as an adjective).

Comment: These comments are great, thanks! @user3169 A cursory search on American/English websites did not give me any example of this, leading me to wonder if I am mistaken, and that all examples I have seen has been from non-natives like me. I did however find the opposite: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12857 has a link called _Schematic_, pointing to a multi-page document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually puzzled me too for a while. When writing academic papers, I usually employ the longer term *schematic diagram*. Sometimes, however, I prefer to employ the shorter form *schematic* to save space. And sometimes *schematic diagram* is shortened into *schematic* directly by the copy editors.

Up to a couple of months ago, when a coauthor of mine questioned my beliefs, I was convinced that *schematics* was a singular noun ending in *s*, just like physics, mathematics etc. But it's not: the singular noun is *schematic*, without the *s*.

From the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/schematic):

> **Schematic** *noun*
>   (In technical contexts) a schematic diagram, in particular of an electric or electronic circuit

From [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/schematic):

> **Schematic** *noun* [C]
>   a ​drawing or ​plan that ​shows the ​details of how something ​operates or is put together

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schematic):

> **Schematic** *noun*
>   a schematic drawing or diagram

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20schematic%20of%20a%2C%20the%20schematics%20of%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20schematic%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20schematics%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0), too, shows a prevalence of *schematic* for the singular form:

[image: Ngram for "the schematic(s) of a"]

I suspect, thus, that the usage of *schematics* for a single diagram is just a common mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Most nouns ending in -ics look like a plural form but they are normally singular.

- Physics is a special branch of science.

Other examples: mathematics, acoustics, mechanics, optics, statistics, dynamics, therapeutics etc.

There are also nouns with the ending -ics that don't denote scientific branches such as lyrics.

Occasionally there is also a plural, often with a slight change of meaning as rhetoric x rhetorics.